# Joining Table Logic

Tags: join, select

So i have this four table userId,ApplicationNo,AttachedNo,RequirementNo now the only given data is userId 20170001 how can i join the tables and get all of their data?

Model:

```
public function get_requirementAttached()
{
$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('user','loanapplication');
    $this->db->where('user.userId', $this->session->userdata('userId'));
    $this->db->join('loanapplication', 'loanapplication.userId = user.userId', 'left');
    $this->db->join('requirementattached', 'requirementattached.ApplicationNo = loanapplication.ApplicationNo', 'left');
    $this->db->join('requirements', 'requirements.RequirementNo = requirementattached.RequirementNo', 'left');
    $query = $this->db->get();       
    return $query->result();
```

Controller:

```
$details = $this->foo_require->get_requirementAttached();
$data['ApplicationNo'] = $details[0]->ApplicationNo;
var_dump($data);exit;
```

Filtered the ApplicationNo here and resulted to null data

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM user, application, requirements;
WHERE userId='session(userId)';
FULL JOIN loanapplication ON loanapplication.userId =user.userId ;
FULL JOIN requirementattached ON requirementattached.ApplicationNo =loanapplication.ApplicationNo ;
FULL JOIN requirements ON requirements.RequirementNo =requirementattached.RequirementNo ;
```

Comment: Which framework or API are you using to access the database? What's the proper syntax for the `where` part  using this API? Is there any (easy) way to get the actual SQL statement generated by this API?

Comment: i have used codeigniter framework @joanolo and proper syntax would be $this->db->where('table.column', $variable_set);

Comment: i have given the sql statement above

Comment: Don't know codeigniter, but from a standard SQL perspective: You've got two tables mentioned in the `from` statement (`user`, `loanapplicaiton`), but there are two other that are joined in (`requirementattached`, `requirements`); should those be tied into the from in some way, or will only the `from` tables' columns be returned. Also, `loanapplication` is left-joined to user, so users without loan applications can be returned. Are you sure the `userId` you used has an application? Check a field from `user`, and see if that brought something back.

Comment: I believe @joanolo is asking for the actual SQL statement as it's sent to your database. Not necessarily having in-depth knowledge of how codeigniter builds a SQL statement, we could tell you much more about what to expect from the statement as sent to the database than from the code you use to tell codeigniter how to build the statement. Looking for something like `SELECT * FROM user INNER JOIN loanapplication ... WHERE user.userId = 20170001`

Comment: I think you just need to do something like `echo $this->db->_compile_select();` before your `$query = $this->db->get();`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010128/echo-query-before-execution-and-without-execution-in-codeigniter-active-record

Comment: The SQL you provided in your answer has lots of `;` that shouldn't be there. And (sorry) but the syntax would be wrong. A SQL statement must have `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...` in this specific order. CodeIgniter *might* allow you to use whatever order, and then rearrange when you actually call `db->get`. See my previous comment.

Comment: yup sorry for wrong sql syntax this codeigniter tolerates un ordered syntax... does $this->db->_compile_select(); mean gathering all selected data?

Comment: Note also - the SQL you provided shows different table names from your actual code (`application` vs `loanapplication`), and shows `FULL OUTER JOIN`s between tables, instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s. And, I believe @joanolo is suggesting that `$this->db->_compile_select()` may build the actual select statement, and `echo`ing that might print that statement out, so you can add it to your post. Also - note that you are copied on all comments to your post, but we are only notified when our usernames are included (preceded by @). If you're directing a reply to me, you'd add @RDFozz to it.

Comment: This seems more like a codeigniter question/problem than a SQL one.

Comment: yeah sorry i think have entered the wrong stack exchange for asking question by the way thanks @RDFozz  for helping..

Comment: and great advice from @joanolo

Answer (score 2):

From a SQL perspective, it looks like the query you're trying to create would be:

```
SELECT *
  FROM user
         LEFT JOIN loanapplication loanapp ON (user.userId = loanapp.userId)
           LEFT JOIN requirementattached reqAtt ON (loanapp.ApplicationNo = reqAtt.ApplicationNo)
             LEFT JOIN requirements req ON (req.RequirementNo = reqAtt.RequirementNo)
 WHERE user.userId = @userid
;
```

Note: table aliases (`loanapp`, `reqAtt`, `req`) used for readability; the actual query would not have the aliases, and would use the full table names wherever I'm using the aliases.

Also, `@userid` wouldn't be in the query, that's just acting as a placeholder - you would have the value from `$this->session->userdata('userId')` here.

The way this query works is it returns all rows (presumably 0 or 1) from `user` with the specified `userId`. If there are any rows in `loanapplication` for this `userId`, each of those columns is appended to the columns from `user`. The same process repeats for `requirementattached` and `requirements`. Where there is no matching row in one of the `LEFT JOIN`ed tables, all columns for that talbe are still present, but their values are all set to `NULL`

Now - If there's no `user` record for the session's current user, your result set will have 0 rows in it. If there is a user record, but there are no `loanapplication` rows with that `userId`, then loanapplication.ApplicationNo will be `NULL`. This matches what you've described.

However, you should note that you have at least two columns in your result set named `userId`. The same hold true for `ApplicationNo` and `RequirementNo`. I cannot say for certain whether both of those columns are available through your API, nor which column's value you are accessing.

It's also true that if you had a row for the `user`, and at least one `loanapplication` row with that same `userId`, but there were no `requirementattached` rows for the `ApplicationNo`, then `loanapplication.ApplicationNo` would have a value, but `requirementattached.ApplicationNo` would be `NULL`.

As noted in the comments, we can't be entirely certain that the SQL statement being run is the precise one I've shown above, unless we can get your API to show you that statement. We also don't know what your DBMS system is; for some systems at least, there may be a tool that can capture commands sent to the database, and you might be able to find the actual SQL command that way, if absolutely necessary.

If possible, get the actual SQL statement, use a command-line or GUI tool that lets you have an interactive connection with the database, and run the full statement there, so you can see the full results. Then, you'll know for sure whether the results that you're seeing in your application are correct for the current data, or if there's some problem.

A further note: whenever possible, limit the columns you include in the `SELECT` list to the ones you actually need. It speeds up sending the results from the DB server to your application, and can result in a faster query on the database end. You can also avoid the potential issues of having two columns with the same names in your result set. You'll have to check on your API to determine if you can do this.